# output environment variables as key-value pairs in a JSON object

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, jq

It seems that with jq I would have to loop around for each variable and append this to a growing json file, but I would need to have variables on both the field name side and the value side?

Any solutions or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQ already has a builtin for that

```
jq -n env > env.json
```